# How do I configure an output device for PyAudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I have been looking for a method to play a wavfile on a specific output-device using a PyAudio-stream.
The documentation of the stream-class initialization hasn't provided any further information :(
The wav file playing part is done, so the only thing that remains is the device configuration
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came up with the solution myself:

You gotta pass the keyword argument "output_device_index" into the stream class constructor
Namely:

```py
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format              = p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
    channels            = wf.getnchannels(),
    rate                = wf.getframerate(),
    output              = True,
    output_device_index = 16
)
```